# Generic Методы, в чем причина " доброты " компилятора?

Tags: java, generics, методы, компилятор

```
class Utilities {       
    public static <T> void flo(T k, T p){}
}

public class UtilitiesTest {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Utilities.flo(5,"5"); //почему компилятор не выдает ошибку?
    }
}
```

T как одиночный параметр generic предполагает одинаковость типов, так? Так на основе чего компилятор не ругается, что "Минутку, ты задал две разные типы, а надо данные одного и того же типа передать"

А вот в данном случае, как бы логично, почему компилятор не ругается.

```
class Utilities {
    public static <T1,T2> void flo(T1 k, T2 p){}
}

public class UtilitiesTest {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Utilities.flo(5,"5"); //а в данном случае понятно почему компилятор спокоен
   }
}
```

Но вот если в этом примере

```
class Utilities {
    public static <T> void fill(List<T> list, T val) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            list.set(i, val);
    }
}

public class UtilitiesTest {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        intList.add(10);
        intList.add(20);
        System.out.println("The original list is: " + intList);
        Utilities.fill(intList, 5);
        System.out.println("The list after calling Utilities.fill() is: " + intList);
    }
}
```

провести эксперимент, то тут компилятор почему то вспоминает про свою обязанность (в смысле, обязанность "ругаться")

```
class Utilities {
    public static <T> void fill(List<T> list, T val) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            list.set(i, val);
    }
}

public class UtilitiesTest {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();
        intList.add(10);
        intList.add(20);
        System.out.println("The original list is: " + intList);
        Utilities.fill(intList, "5"); //хоть тут компилятор ругается!
        System.out.println("The list after calling Utilities.fill() is: " + intList);
    }
}
```

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вывод типов параметров дженериков работает в несколько стадий. Сначала определяются типы данных, участвующих в передаче аргументов и присвоениях. В данном случае это будут разные типы - `Integer` и `String`. Затем подбирается наиболее частный тип, под который могли бы подойти отобранные типы. В данном случае видимо `Serializable` - от него наследуются как `Integer`, так и `String`. Этот тип и выбирается в качестве параметра дженерика.

В последнем примере использование `Serializable` в качестве параметра потребовало бы использования `List<Serializable>` в качестве первого аргумента и вывод наиболее подходящего типа заканчивается неудачей, так как `List<Integer>`, передаваемый в качестве первого параметра, не наследуется от `List<Serializable>` несмотря на то, то `Integer` наследует от `Serializable`. Вообще говоря, передача `List<Integer>` в качестве первого параметра сразу сужает список типов, потенциально подходящих в качестве параметра дженерика, до `Integer`, так как `List<Integer>` мог бы приводиться только к `Collection<Integer>` или `Iterable<Integer>`.

Comment: Пардон. Но не понял, почему именно Serializable выбирается. Как мне известно сама Сериализация (Serialization) — это процесс, который переводит объект в последовательность байтов, по которой затем его можно полностью восстановить. а интерфейс Serializable — идентификатор, который не имеет методов, но он указывает jvm, что объекты этого класса могут быть сериализованы. Как то в рамках данного уровня знакомства со сутью Сериализации и механизма его работы мне не удаётся понять ваш ответ.

Comment: @RubenKubalyan общий корень в иерархии наследования.

Comment: Хорошо. Проверил доки и сделал эксперименты. Результат: увидел, что при public static <T1> void flo(T1 k, T1 p){} любые переданные типы принимаются, даже если одновременно  один T1 аргумент является Integer а другой String или вообще объект другого класса. Но при  public static <T1> void flo(List<T1> k, T1 p){} компилятор ругается, если тип генерика первого аргумента отличается от типа второго аргумента. Все мои попытки понять - не дали никакого положительного результата.

Comment: Уточню. Первый абзац самого высшего ответа я понял. А вот со вторым абзацом - проблемы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: @VTT  ........................            .

Comment: @RubenKubalyan Расписал поподробнее

Comment: @VTT я это уже заметил, но все же - очень рад, что вы  более подробно описали как все работает, по крайней мере я получил подтверждение, что я смог до этого прийти к правильному пониманию.  Это радует. Спасибо за помощь.